# Loadrunner Server Response parameter not found Javascript

Tags: javascript, load-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have a server application to submit data which worked fine in the Browser , I try to create a VuGe script for that, which checks a pattern from the Server Response with the reg_save_param function which looks so:

```
web_reg_save_param("gcid",
                         "LB=<span", 
                         "RB=</span>", 
                         LAST );

web_reg_save_param("X",
                       "LB={", 
                       "RB=}", 
                       LAST );
```

, but the pattern i.e "gcid" which must be an alphanumeric value,can not be found in the response,, instead of ,it looks like a html element with a tag, the same applies to the "X" parameter, and this is the Response I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
Action.c(144):     <html id="ng-app" ng-app="gcdm-cockpit">\n
Action.c(144):     <head>\n
Action.c(144):         <meta charset="utf-8">\n
Action.c(144):         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">\n
Action.c(144):         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\n
Action.c(144):         <title>GCDM Cockpit</title>\n
Action.c(144):         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="all"/>\n
Action.c(144):         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" media="all"/>\n
Action.c(144):         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awe
Action.c(144):     some.min.css">\n
Action.c(144):         <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->\n
Action.c(144):         <!--[if lt IE 9]>\n
Action.c(144):         <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>\n
Action.c(144):         <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>\n
Action.c(144):         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/2.2.0/es5-shim.min.js"></
Action.c(144):     script>\n
Action.c(144):         <![endif]-->\n
Action.c(144):         <!--[if lte IE 8]>\n
Action.c(144):         <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.0/json3.min.js"></script>\n
Action.c(144):         <![endif]-->\n
Action.c(144):     </head>\n
Action.c(144):     <body ng-controller="CockpitController">\n
Action.c(144):     \n
Action.c(144):         <div class="container-fluid" cockpit-app\n
Action.c(144):              cockpit-api-key="ddd"\n
Action.c(144):              cockpit-api-endpoint='{{ isLocalNonStubMode() ? "https://gcdm-cockpit-test.natura
Action.c(144):     .net/mon/" : "/mon/" }}'\n
Action.c(144):              cockpit-default-frame-endpoint="<%= defaultFrameEndpoint %>"\n
Action.c(144):              cockpit-portal-frame-endpoint="<%= portalFrameEndpoint %>">\n
Action.c(144):     \n
Action.c(144):     \n
Action.c(144):             <span cockpit-menu class="menu"></span>\n
Action.c(144):     \n
Action.c(144):             <div class="row">\n
Action.c(144):                 <div class="col-md-8">\n
Action.c(144):                     <div id="view" ng-view></div>\n
Action.c(144):                 </div>\n
Action.c(144):             </div>\n
Action.c(144):     \n
Action.c(144):         </div>\n
Action.c(144):     \n
Action.c(144):         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v3.4.8.min.js"></script>\n
Action.c(144):         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gcdm-cockpit.js"></script>\n
Action.c(144):     \n
Action.c(144):     </body>\n
Action.c(144):     </html>\n
Action.c(144):     \n
Action.c(144): Notify: Saving Parameter "X =  isLocalNonStubMode() ? "https://gcdm-cockpit-test.natura.net/mon/" : "/mon/" ".
Action.c(144): Notify: Saving Parameter "gcid =  cockpit-menu class="menu">".
```

When I submit data on the browser (Firefox), it worked fine, and by clicking the Firefox tool Page Inspector "inspect element", I can clearly found the request body and the response body, and also I can found the pattern I looked for, which I can't found it on th Vugen Script

```
    Request-URL:    https://gcdm-cockpit-test.natura.net/mon/protected/api/v3/services/getUserGCID
Request-Methode:    POST
Status-Code:    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Request-Header 11:23:52.000
username:   Tobias Testman
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Referer:    https://gcdm-cockpit-test.natura.net/
Pragma: no-cache
Host:   gcdm-cockpit-test.natura.net
Content-Type:   application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 85
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Authorization:  Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0
Accept-Language:    de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Gesendetes Cookie
SMIDENTITY: 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
Request-Body
{"environment":"opint","userIdentifier":"gcdmtest_bp_pr_acc_po_00499@trash-mail.com"}
Response-Header Δ309ms
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Date:   Tue, 03 Nov 2015 10:23:52 GMT
Content-Type:   application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
Response-Body Δ0ms
{"data":["1755c83a-9303-459a-a741-68131b439eb0"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your left boundary and right boundary conditions are not sufficiently distinct to narrow to the one item you want to capture.  Narrow the scope of what is captured to a more distinct boundary.

Also, make sure that you are placing your capture markers in the correct location, above where you want to capture the element.  the web_reg_.. series of functions act like a sieve/filter through which the HTML is passed and the value is left in the filter.

If you need the value of 1755c83a-.... then you should look at a **"LB={\"data\":[\""** & **"RB=\"]}"** with **"ORD=1"**

Comment: the problem is the pattern is not visible in the response at all,though I do ditinct my boundary as you suggested, I think the response is some kind of javascript which  impeds this pattern to be shown, and I don't how to fix that

Comment: Then run your JavaScript as a function.  There are a number of ways to address this.  If you do a Google search for "run JavaScript inside of a LoadRunner web user" you should find some nice articles by HP.  In the latest release you also have the option of a JavaScript language virtual user